# Why can't add the second element in this list?

Tags: c, linked-list

I wanted to create a list to save names, but if a name is already in the list, i ignore the new element with the same name.
I can't add a second element: gdb says that

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000555555554c20 in search (nome=0x5555557576d0 "carl")
at desktop/test.c:*line*
*line*          while(strcmp(nome,temp->name)!=0&&f==0){
```

If a element searched isn't in the list, the search function should return NULL.

```
typedef struct node{
char *name;
struct node *n;
} N;
N *h=NULL;

void insert(char *name){
N *temp=malloc(sizeof(N));
if(h==NULL){
    h=temp;
    temp->n=NULL;
    temp->name=strdup(name);
}
else{
    N *curr=h;
    while(curr->n!=NULL)
        curr=curr->n;
    curr->n=temp;
    temp->name=strdup(name);
}
}



N *search(char *name){
N *temp=h;
int f=0;
if(temp==NULL)
    return NULL;
else{
    while(strcmp(nome,temp->name)!=0&&f==0){
     temp=temp->n;
     if(temp==NULL)
        f=1;        
    }
    if(f==1)
        return NULL;
    else
        return temp;
}
}


int main(){
char *name=//getting input without problems;              
        N *temp=esearch(name);
        if(temp==NULL) 
            insert(name);

//this four lines sequence repeats for every input (stdin)
}
```

Comment: You can get rid of the `f` variable in `search`. Just put `return NULL` where you do `f = 1`.

Comment: ok, true, now i'll do it

Comment: What do you think the error message is telling you?

Comment: You have lots of typos. You call a function `esearch()` instead of `search()`, and you test the variable `nome` instead of `name`.

Comment: temp->name is out of the list? but i don't know how to fix the code

Comment: @Barmar yeah sorry, there are these typos 'cause i transrcribed this part of code

Comment: Finding out what `temp` is on the line where the error occurs would be a good start. Use a debugger to step through that and take a look. Then look at your code and figure out where that `temp` came from. Learning to solve this kind of thing yourself takes time and effort, but it's the only way to move on.

Comment: @Caleb you so right, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `insert` you forget to set the last nodes "next" pointer `n` to `NULL`.

---

Another problem is that your `search` function doesn't check for `temp` being a null pointer in the correct order.

I suggest you change your code to something like

```
else
{
    while (temp != NULL && strcmp(nome, temp->name) != 0)
    {
        temp = temp->n;
    }

    return temp;
}
```

With the above change, if you run off the end of the list and `temp` becomes `NULL` then the loop will end and you will return `NULL` (`temp` will in this case be `NULL`).

If the name is found then the loop ends and `temp` will point to that node, and you will return that node.

The code you have will not work because logical AND (`&&`) will perform the left-hand side expression first, and then you will dereference the null pointer `temp` leading to *undefined behavior* and a probable crash.

---

Both of these problems should be easy to find out by using a debugger.

The first problem could be spotted by using the debugger to step through the code while monitoring the variables and their values. Then it should be easy to spot that the `n` member would have some "random" or "garbage" value (the value is *indeterminate*).

The second problem should be possible to figure out by catching the crash with a debugger and seeing that the pointer `temp` would be `NULL` in the `strcmp` call. Then restarting the program and stepping through the code line by line again, it would be easy to see when the pointer becomes `NULL`. Knowing about how the `&&` operator works and how its [short-circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) nature leads to the left-hand side always being evaluated first also would help with the understanding.

Comment: The code that fills in the fields of `temp` should be moved out of the `if` and `else` blocks, since it's the same whether the new node is being added at the end or is the first node.

Comment: in which functions? how would you change it?

Comment: @Palomc In `insert`, you can do the `temp->n=NULL;` and `temp->name=strdup(name);` before the `if`. In your current version you only do `temp->n=NULL;` in the `if` branch, so it will be left as a junk pointer in the `else` branch.

Comment: @Palomc Updated answer with a fix for your `search` function.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude just done, in this way should be correct?

Comment: @Palomc Please don't update the original code in the question! That makes my answer useless as one of the problems are no longer valid.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude also could you tell me if there is a memory leak? I have a doubt about it